# Table missing after database migration [cakephp]

Tags: cakephp, migration

I used to have a login form in Mysql. Then I migrated to SQL Server 2008. I included the following file: `lib\Cake\Model\Datasource\Database\Sqlsrv.php`.

In database.php:

```
    public $default = array(
    'datasource' => 'Database/Sqlsrv',
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'login' => 'sa',
    'password' => 'mypass',
    'database' => 'db_crm',
    'port' => '1433',
    'mars' => false,
    'charset' => SQLSRV_ENC_CHAR,       
);
```

It shows me the following error:

> Missing Database Table
>
> Error: Table users for model User was not found in datasource default.
>
> Notice: If you want to customize this error message, create
>   app\View\Errors\missing_table.ctp

Does anybody know the reason?

Comment: Some people gave me -1, but nobody has told me what is wrong. Is this a repeated question?, Is the structure malformed?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't setup any Model (Database) in your project. CakePHP will autometic link user's table to "users" table.
Do you have "users" table in your database?

more info: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer.
I do have table users. I have erased the cache and nothing, disable the cache and nothing. It seems that cakephp can´t list any table in db, because the following code doesn´t show any data:

                $db = ConnectionManager::getDataSource('default');
  debug($db->listSources());

I have tried everything and nothing seems to work :(
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since CakePHP 1.3 you have to have a simple `users` table, otherwise this message will always appear.

just create a dummy table with:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (id int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT, bool tinyint(1), small_int tinyint(2), primary key(id));
```